# How to sum data without group by in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to do sum of number_of_count data based on body_corporate field, here i have put my query, here i have put my result of data

```
userid body_corporate number_of_count
 1     bodycorporate1     1
 1     bodycorporate1     5
 0     Unassigned        732


SELECT 
    IF(tblclients.userid IS NULL,
        0,
        tblclients.userid) AS userid,
    IF(tblmeter.body_corporate_id IS NULL,
        'Unassigned',
        tblclients.company) AS body_corporate,
    COUNT(DISTINCT tbltransactions.description) AS number_of_count,
    SUM(IF(tbltransactions.post_type = 'Collection',
        tbltransactions.transaction_amount,
        0)) AS total_sales,
    IF(tblmeter.body_corporate_id IS NULL,
        0,
        tblclients.commission) AS commision,
    (SUM(IF(tbltransactions.post_type = 'Collection',
        tbltransactions.transaction_amount,
        0) * IF(tblmeter.body_corporate_id IS NULL,
        0,
        tblclients.commission)) / 100) AS totalCommission,
    CONCAT(MONTHNAME(tbltransactions.date_time),
            '-',
            YEAR(tbltransactions.date_time)) AS billing_period
FROM
    tbltransactions
        LEFT JOIN
    tblmeter ON tblmeter.id = tbltransactions.meter_id
        LEFT JOIN
    tblclients ON tblclients.userid = tblmeter.body_corporate_id
GROUP BY tblmeter.body_corporate_id , YEAR(tbltransactions.date_time) , MONTH(tbltransactions.date_time)
ORDER BY IF(tblclients.userid IS NULL,
    0,
    tblclients.userid) DESC
LIMIT 0 , 25
```

i want result like this

```
userid body_corporate number_of_count
     1     bodycorporate1     6
     1     bodycorporate1     6
     0     Unassigned        732
```

can anyone please help me how to get this output ?

Comment: Use window `SUM() OVER ()` (if MySQL version allows).

Comment: it is not working

Comment: Of course it cannot work directly - you use COUNT() for to obtain separate values to 
be summed, and "aggregate in aggregate" is not allowed. Move your query into CTE and use window function in main query.

Comment: over partition by will not work in mysql, it will only work in sql

Comment: @Nikul Panchal The window function introduced in MySQL since version 8.0 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html

Comment: Why would you want duplicates in the result set?

Answer (score 0):

Start from MySQL 8 you can use window function `SUM() OVER ()`:

```
SELECT 
    userid,
    body_corporate,
    SUM(number_of_count) OVER(PARTITION BY body_corporate) AS s
FROM
    test;
```

For previous DB version `GROUP BY` & `JOIN` can be used:

```
SELECT 
    test.userid,
    test.body_corporate,
    summary.number_of_count
FROM
    test
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        body_corporate,
        SUM(number_of_count) AS number_of_count
    FROM test
    GROUP BY body_corporate
) AS summary ON summary.body_corporate = test.body_corporate;
```

See SQL example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=527397d8394bf1d6e7f101863f25b808)